# como eliminar scroll derecha?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

hola tengo una consulta como elimino el scroll de la derecha? me queda la pagina mas grande de lo que debería y no se como sacárselo ,alguna sugerencia?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<body id="page-top">

    <nav class="navbar-navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-1 text-white" href="index.html">Tarjeta Fiel | Solicitud web</a>

</nav>
<div id="wrappers">

<div id="content-wrappers">
<div class="container-fluids" >
</div>
</v-app> 
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: agrega esto en tu archivo `css` `body, html {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Con `::-webkit-scrollbar`. La barra como un elemento más del documento.

Comment: @Daniel eso es lo que buscaba hacer ,el único problema con esa solución es que me borra el footer que tengo mas abajo

Comment: @Mateo como se implementa ?

Comment: @RodrigoCamacho pensé que no tenias nada abajo de esas tablas, en ese caso te recomiendo que le des una altura especifica al contenedor de las tablas un ejemplo `height: 95vh;` con eso, la tabla a mostrarse siempre con ese tamaño en cualquier pantalla, por lo tanto el footer va subir un poco arriba y va a desaparecer la ultima barra de scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es el selector `::-webkit-scrollbar`. Un ejemplo:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

[Aquí está la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)